# What should someone who became a vegan do with their non-vegan possessions?

Tags: veganism, ethics

For example, someone decides to go vegan but already owns a leather jacket?

What should they do with this jacket and any other non-vegan possessions?

Comment: If you reworded this to include your moral specification (utilitarian, whatever), then I think it should be re-openable? Although I suspect if you knew which morals are relevant to you here, then you would also know the answer.

Comment: I think asking for opinions - as in, what are the commonly held (differing) views in a given community - should be considered very on topic here. Any -ism is defined by factions with opinions, pipe and smoke it. Opinions ARE the facts (about worldview/philosophy within that community) asked for here.

Comment: I agree that the question was worded badly and it being opinion based kinda defeats the purpose as that's a fallacy in terms of actually supporting or discrediting any '-ism'. That being said, my intention wasn't to get an answer to myself, but as an example question to gather points for and against aligned with any moral specification for this matter. I probably should have also considered answering this myself but the answer by @Kess Vargavind covers at least the ethical aspect of this well.

Answer (score 8):

Ask yourself, in the end it is you who decides.

**Keeping the old non-vegan stuff but not getting any new**; you find it ethical and sound to keep wearing your leather jacket because you are honoring the donor, so to speak. You would feel guilty to throw it away rather than keep using it till the end.

**Giving it away instead**; you find it abhorring to keep using that leather jacket, but you have no heart to throw it away. Letting someone else use it is totally fine with you though.

**Throwing it away**; you absolutely cannot see yourself or someone else use that leather jacket. You have to throw it away. Perhaps you feel a need for some last rites to be perxormed?

Again, ask yourself. It is only you who knows your own mind and heart.